# Unable to Save BelongsTo Data Using Checkboxes in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have two models with the relationship `Advisor belongsTo Room`, `Room hasMany Advisor`. `Advisor` has a foreignKey constraint in the database (`Advisor.room_id`) which points to a specific room. The default value for this is the `NULL` value (representing an advisor without a room).

Suppose I had an `Advisor`, with `room_id` set to `n`. I now wish to unassign the the `nth` room from `Advisor` - using a select field, I can reset `room_id` to `NULL`, with the following `request->data` structure:

```
[Room] => Array
    (
        [name] => TestRoom2
        [type] => single suite
        [id] => 4
    )

[Advisor] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 14
                [room_id] => 
                [name] => foo
            )
    )
```

However, when I attempt to do this through the use of checkboxes with the same generated `$this->request->data`, MySQL refuses to update the `NULL` value.

In addition, it seems that changing the value of `room_id` explicitly in `request->data` in the second case has no effect. However, if I were to change `Advisor.0.name` to `hax`, (by modifying `request->data` directly) the `name` field *does* save.

I save via calling `$this->Room->saveAll($request->data, array('deep' => true))` - this is true both in the case of the select field and the checkbox.

I am generating the series of checkboxes by repeatedly calling the `Form` helper:

```
$count = 0;
// $key is the Advisor id, and $attributes is an array of the form
//      array('name' => (string), 'disabled' => (bool))
foreach($options['advisorList'] as $key => $attributes) {
    $form[] = $this->Form->hidden(sprintf('Advisor.%s.id', $count), array('value' => $key));
    $form[] = $this->Form->input(sprintf('Advisor.%s.room_id', $count), array(
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'label' => $attributes['name'],
        'disabled' => $attributes['disabled']));
    $count++;
}
```

*Moreover*, if `room_id` has already been set to `NULL`, there is no problem setting `room_id` - except, `room_id` will be set regardless if the checkbox is checked or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! This has to do with funky cakePHP $model->saveAll() on hasMany relationships.

In order to correctly update this form, all advisors that **may** be changed in saveAll() must unset their relationship to their respective rooms and saved in the database

```
foreach($copyOfData['Advisor'] as $advisor) {
    $advisor['room_id'] = null;
    $this->Advisor->save(array('Advisor' => $advisor));
}
```

Only after this has been done, can we call `$this->Advisor->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true))` and have `saveAll()` behave as expected.